# How do i put text after an image slider

Tags: html, css

This is the code

```html
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahatma_Gandhi">
  <h1>Mahatma Gandhi</h1>
</a>
<div class="slidershow middle">
  <div class="slides">
    <input type="radio" name="r" id="r1" checked>
    <input type="radio" name="r" id="r2">
    <input type="radio" name="r" id="r3">
    <input type="radio" name="r" id="r4">
    <input type="radio" name="r" id="r5">
    <div class="slide s1">
      <img class="image" src="Mahatma.jpg" alt="Mahatma-Gandhi">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="Gandhi.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="Gandhi2.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="Gandhi1.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="Gandhiji3.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="navigation">
    <label for="r1" class="bar"></label>
    <label for="r2" class="bar"></label>
    <label for="r3" class="bar"></label>
    <label for="r4" class="bar"></label>
    <label for="r5" class="bar"></label>
  </div>
</div>

<h2>1969-1948</h2>
<h2>"An eye for eye only ends up making the whole world blind."</h2>


<h3>Biography</h3>
//This part here is not coming after the slider
<p>
  Mohandas Karamchand Gandhi (2 October 1869 – 30 January 1948) was an Indian lawyer, anti-colonial nationalist, and political ethicist, who employed nonviolent resistance to lead the successful campaign for India's independence from British rule, and in
  turn inspired movements for civil rights and freedom across the world. The honorific Mahātmā first applied to him in 1914 in South Africa, is now used throughout the world. Born and raised in a Hindu family in coastal Gujarat, western India, Gandhi
  trained in law at the Inner Temple, London, and was called to the bar at age 22 in June 1891. After two uncertain years in India, where he was unable to start a successful law practice, he moved to South Africa in 1893 to represent an Indian merchant
  in a lawsuit. He went on to stay for 21 years. It was in South Africa that Gandhi raised a family, and first employed nonviolent resistance in a campaign for civil rights. In 1915, aged 45, he returned to India. He set about organising peasants, farmers,
  and urban labourers to protest against excessive land-tax and discrimination. Assuming leadership of the Indian National Congress in 1921, Gandhi led nationwide campaigns for easing poverty, expanding women's rights, building religious and ethnic amity,
  ending untouchability, and above all for achieving Swaraj or self-rule. The same year Gandhi adopted the Indian loincloth, or short dhoti and, in the winter, a shawl, both woven with yarn hand-spun on a traditional Indian spinning wheel, or charkha,
  as a mark of identification with India's rural poor. Thereafter, he lived modestly in a self-sufficient residential community, ate simple vegetarian food, and undertook long fasts as a means of self-purification and political protest. Bringing anti-colonial
  nationalism to the common Indians, Gandhi led them in challenging the British-imposed salt tax with the 400 km (250 mi) Dandi Salt March in 1930, and later in calling for the British to Quit India in 1942. He was imprisoned for many years, upon many
  occasions, in both South Africa and India. Gandhi's vision of an independent India based on religious pluralism was challenged in the early 1940s by a new Muslim nationalism which was demanding a separate Muslim homeland carved out of India. In August
  1947, Britain granted independence, but the British Indian Empire was partitioned into two dominions, a Hindu-majority India and Muslim-majority Pakistan. As many displaced Hindus, Muslims, and Sikhs made their way to their new lands, religious violence
  broke out, especially in the Punjab and Bengal. Eschewing the official celebration of independence in Delhi, Gandhi visited the affected areas, attempting to provide solace. In the months following, he undertook several fasts unto death to stop religious
  violence. The last of these, undertaken on 12 January 1948 when he was 78, also had the indirect goal of pressuring India to pay out some cash assets owed to Pakistan. Some Indians thought Gandhi was too accommodating. Among them was Nathuram Godse,
  a Hindu nationalist, who assassinated Gandhi on 30 January 1948 by firing three bullets into his chest. Gandhi's birthday, 2 October, is commemorated in India as Gandhi Jayanti, a national holiday, and worldwide as the International Day of Nonviolence.
  Gandhi is commonly, though not formally, considered the Father of the Nation in India, and was commonly called Bapu.
</p>
```

This is how it looks like
[image]

Comment: now what want to do, please add some explanation

Comment: I want the text to come below the image slider

Comment: Using "alt" attribute  as a text for an image is totally bad  practic. You better  place image text  into some container below image.

Comment: do you want all that text or another paragraph?

Comment: All that text above

Answer (score 0):

```css
.left,.right{
width:100%;
float:left;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahatma_Gandhi">
  <h1>Mahatma Gandhi</h1>
</a>
<div class="left">
  <div class="slidershow middle">
    <div class="slides">
      <input type="radio" name="r" id="r1" checked>
      <input type="radio" name="r" id="r2">
      <input type="radio" name="r" id="r3">
      <input type="radio" name="r" id="r4">
      <input type="radio" name="r" id="r5">
      <div class="slide s1">
        <img class="image" src="Mahatma.jpg" alt="Mahatma-Gandhi">
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="Gandhi.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="Gandhi2.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="Gandhi1.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="Gandhiji3.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="navigation">
      <label for="r1" class="bar"></label>
      <label for="r2" class="bar"></label>
      <label for="r3" class="bar"></label>
      <label for="r4" class="bar"></label>
      <label for="r5" class="bar"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="right">
  <h2>1969-1948</h2>
  <h2>"An eye for eye only ends up making the whole world blind."</h2>


  <h3>Biography</h3>
  //This part here is not coming after the slider
  <p>
    Mohandas Karamchand Gandhi (2 October 1869 – 30 January 1948) was an Indian lawyer, anti-colonial nationalist, and political ethicist, who employed nonviolent resistance to lead the successful campaign for India's independence from British rule, and in
    turn inspired movements for civil rights and freedom across the world. The honorific Mahātmā first applied to him in 1914 in South Africa, is now used throughout the world. Born and raised in a Hindu family in coastal Gujarat, western India, Gandhi
    trained in law at the Inner Temple, London, and was called to the bar at age 22 in June 1891. After two uncertain years in India, where he was unable to start a successful law practice, he moved to South Africa in 1893 to represent an Indian merchant
    in a lawsuit. He went on to stay for 21 years. It was in South Africa that Gandhi raised a family, and first employed nonviolent resistance in a campaign for civil rights. In 1915, aged 45, he returned to India. He set about organising peasants, farmers,
    and urban labourers to protest against excessive land-tax and discrimination. Assuming leadership of the Indian National Congress in 1921, Gandhi led nationwide campaigns for easing poverty, expanding women's rights, building religious and ethnic
    amity, ending untouchability, and above all for achieving Swaraj or self-rule. The same year Gandhi adopted the Indian loincloth, or short dhoti and, in the winter, a shawl, both woven with yarn hand-spun on a traditional Indian spinning wheel, or
    charkha, as a mark of identification with India's rural poor. Thereafter, he lived modestly in a self-sufficient residential community, ate simple vegetarian food, and undertook long fasts as a means of self-purification and political protest. Bringing
    anti-colonial nationalism to the common Indians, Gandhi led them in challenging the British-imposed salt tax with the 400 km (250 mi) Dandi Salt March in 1930, and later in calling for the British to Quit India in 1942. He was imprisoned for many
    years, upon many occasions, in both South Africa and India. Gandhi's vision of an independent India based on religious pluralism was challenged in the early 1940s by a new Muslim nationalism which was demanding a separate Muslim homeland carved out
    of India. In August 1947, Britain granted independence, but the British Indian Empire was partitioned into two dominions, a Hindu-majority India and Muslim-majority Pakistan. As many displaced Hindus, Muslims, and Sikhs made their way to their new
    lands, religious violence broke out, especially in the Punjab and Bengal. Eschewing the official celebration of independence in Delhi, Gandhi visited the affected areas, attempting to provide solace. In the months following, he undertook several fasts
    unto death to stop religious violence. The last of these, undertaken on 12 January 1948 when he was 78, also had the indirect goal of pressuring India to pay out some cash assets owed to Pakistan. Some Indians thought Gandhi was too accommodating.
    Among them was Nathuram Godse, a Hindu nationalist, who assassinated Gandhi on 30 January 1948 by firing three bullets into his chest. Gandhi's birthday, 2 October, is commemorated in India as Gandhi Jayanti, a national holiday, and worldwide as the
    International Day of Nonviolence. Gandhi is commonly, though not formally, considered the Father of the Nation in India, and was commonly called Bapu.
  </p>
</div>
```